# Real time with raspberry pi CM4

Tags: real-time, raspberry-pi4, preempt-rt

I want to apply real time on my raspberry pi CM4.
My current kernel version is 6.1.19, Is this version available for applying PREEMPT_RT, or I should build a new kernel to apply PREEMPT_RT? and what is the steps to do any of mentioned options?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Remember that merely applying a preempt-rt patch won't magically make your system real time.